# crunchbang - Increase window border thickness

Tags: linux, openbox, crunchbang

Just recently installed CrunchBang Linux 11 "Waldorf".
Would like to know how to increase the border thickness of windows. Or be able to change the threshold of the mouse cursor changing to the window resize cursor. 
I'm finding the fine mouse movements required to resize a window a bit fiddly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look to the openbox wiki: http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Contents#Configuration

So let's say you use the waldorf theme with openbox. You go to /usr/share/themes/waldorf/openbox-3/themerc and search the line

```
border.Width: 1
```

For the part with the mouse I don't know, new to crunchbang too.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: If that link breaks, I guess the question will become useless :D but I see your point. Thanks.